# Make virtual subdomain in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have to create subsomain in my codeigniter application. what i am try is routing my URl in this way

```
www.example.com/subdomain
```

to

```
subdomain.example.com/
```

it is my current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

i use this script to create subdomain on server http://www.webinfopedia.com/create-subdomain-in-php.html
How i do this task. any solution with .htaccess or route.php base.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a php script that can host sub domains dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720447/how-to-make-a-php-script-that-can-host-sub-domains-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tutorial please modify the following line to solve your problem:

```
$buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain . "&dir=public_html/subdomains/" . $subDomain;
```

to this line:

```
$buildRequest = "/frontend/x3/subdomain/doadddomain.html?rootdomain=" . $rootDomain . "&domain=" . $subDomain . "&dir=public_html/" . $subDomain;
```

after that when you access `subdomain.example.com/` then it will automatically show `example.com/` subdomain folder's root index.php or index.html file....

Have fun...

Comment: i did it but it will not redirect automatically. if some .htaccess is necessary?